# Using the optional flanking rule, would a Spiritual Weapon on the other side of an enemy allow a character to benefit from flanking?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, optional-rules, flanking

Using the [optional rules on flanking](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/running-the-game#OptionalRuleFlanking) in the DMG on page 251, would a caster who gains access to the Spiritual Weapon spell be able to use said weapon to trigger the advantage from flanking?

Comment: [Related] [Use of Mage Hand during combat to gain advantage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108635/321)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## By RAW: No, it wouldn't help with flanking.

The flanking rules require that two creatures (specifically allies) are on opposite sides of the creature they flank.

> When **a creature and at
> least one of its allies** are adjacent to an enemy and on
> opposite sides or corners of the enemy's space, they
> flank that enemy [...]

However, a spiritual weapon does not count as a creature or an ally of any other creature, it is simply a floating weapon. It does not occupy space and cannot be attacked.

> You create a **floating, spectral weapon** within range that
> lasts for the duration or until you cast this spell again.
> When you cast the spell, you can make a melee spell
> attack against a creature within 5 feet of the weapon. On
> a hit, the target takes force damage equal to 1d8 + your
> spellcasting ability modifier.

Additionally, it was [confirmed](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/03/16/does-a-spiritual-weapon-count-as-such-an-enemy-for-sneak-attack/) by Jeremy Crawford that Spiritual Weapon does not count as another enemy for sneak attack, which is nearly the same condition.

While many DMs may quite reasonably rule that a floating, spectral weapon would be a sufficient condition to provide advantage, by RAW it does not.

Comment: How do you determine it's not an ally? That's not a defined mechanical term and there are lots of ways a sufficiently creative player could create a character's worldview such that they think of said weapon as an ally.

Comment: You are correct that the term "ally" is not strictly defined in 5e. And I agree that your DM could very reasonably allow it to be used as an ally for flanking. However, 5e uses the English definition of "ally", and a weapon does not constitute a "A person or organization that cooperates with or helps another in a particular activity." (See: [What does 'ally' mean, as a game term?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129130/what-does-ally-mean-as-a-game-term)) Furthermore, if a Spiritual Weapon does not count as an enemy for sneak attack, then it can hardly be an ally for flanking.